# Fast Cross-Platform C/C++ Hashing Library

Tags: c++, c, cross-platform, hash

What's a high performance hashing library that's also cross platform for C/C++. For algorithms such as MD5, SHA1, CRC32 and Adler32.

I initially had the impression that Boost had these, but apparently not (yet).

The most promising one I have found so far is Crypto++, any other suggestions? http://www.cryptopp.com/ This seems to be quite comprehensive.

Comment: I would go for cryptopp.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For usual crypto hashes (MD?, SHA? etc.), [openssl](https://www.openssl.org/) is the most portable and probably fastest. None of the hashes you mentioned are good for high performance data structures like hash tables. The recommended hash functions for these data structures these days are: FNV, Jenkins and MurmurHash.

Comment: interesting. could you post links? (yes I know, I can google those...)

Comment: Thanks, I will look in to openssl. The use of the hashes won't be for hash tables, but used as hashes for authentication and document verifications (was it tampered etc)

Answer (score 4):

QT [seem to implement](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.3/qcryptographichash.html) MD4, MD5 and SHA1

Comment: Why include a whole Widget-library just to use its MD5 and SHA-1 implementations? *If* you're already using QT this could be a feasibel option otherwise it's overkill.

Comment: Doxygen uses QTCore and none of the GUI classes.  It turns out that QT is has a pretty good platform abstraction.  See [Doxygen FAQ](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/faq.html) #9.

Answer (score 2):

I'd definitely go with CryptoPP, it has a nice license to go with it as well.

Comment: Yeah, just nick the code you need and you'll be set.

Answer (score 1):

[zlib](http://www.zlib.net/) has a built-in implementation of a crc32 variant, and is widely ported.  =)

Answer (score 1):

Device cross platform?  If it means to you what it means to me that means not linux or perhaps operating system independent.  I would and did avoid such things as openssl.  I went with libtomcrypt.  Now as far as speed goes?  Well fast, portable, C, chose any two.

Comment: That libtomcrypt locks interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use [libbeecrypt](http://beecrypt.sourceforge.net/)?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [plibsys](https://github.com/saprykin/plibsys) C library: it support MD5, SHA1, SHA-2 (224, 256, 384, 512), SHA-3 (224, 256, 384, 512) and GOST 34.11-94 cryptography hash algorithms. The library is portable and light-weight itself.