# sha1 function in cpp (C++)

Tags: c++, sha1

Ill start by  saying I dont know anything about c++ and I googled, there is nothing that can make me understand how to use SHA1 in C++. found this one though [Objective C: SHA1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468268/objective-c-sha1) but its about objective c im not sure it is the same.

I need to do the following:

I habve a lot of files, i compile them by doing ./make.sh and in one file called server.cpp I need to SHA1 info_hash thats inserted in this part:

```
Csql_query(m_database, "insert into @files (info_hash, mtime, ctime)
 values (?, unix_timestamp(), unix_timestamp())").p(i.first).execute();
```

so I kinda think I need to do the following sha1(?). "?" isnt info_hash i need. i think it generates somewhere and "?" is a variable.

so please dont tell me to add any classes or something else, because i do NOT understand how to do that, if i need to add something in the beggining of the file, please tell me so.

Comment: Do I understand this right? You say that nothing will make you understand how to deal with this problem in C++. We are also not to tell you what to do because you wouldn't understand anyway. Why are you even asking a C++ related question? What kind of answer do you expect? C++ is not PHP, there is no inbuilt `sha1("cat")` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good library for SHA1 and other functions is [cryptopp](https://www.cryptopp.com/).

Here is another question where the answer is cryptopp: [Fast Cross-Platform C/C++ Hashing Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799932/fast-cross-platform-c-c-hashing-library)

Comment: In PHP I do: sha1("cat") PHP returns 9d989e8d27dc9e0ec3389fc855f142c3d40f0c50 how can i do that in C++?

Comment: @Treat: See [How do I use a hash function?](http://www.cryptopp.com/fom-serve/cache/50.html) from the [Crypto++ FAQ](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/FAQ).

Comment: To use SHA() you'll need libssl-dev and then link with -lssl -lcrypto and you can go further with (ARM8 /Graviton2 say) CPU support depending upon flags.  Plenty of examples on GH nowadays given this question is 10 years old. A system call to bash would also be an option if performance does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `.p(i.first)` part already substitutes the value of `i.first` into the `?` in your query. Presumably `i.first` would be a value appropriate for the `info_hash` column.

Without seeing more of your code, it's impossible to say for sure.

Comment: In PHP I do: sha1("cat") PHP returns 9d989e8d27dc9e0ec3389fc855f142c3d40f0c50 how can i do that in C++?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [library that implements SHA1()](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/csha1.aspx) - there are probably better i.e. more efficient libraries but this has a good explanation of how to use it.

If you want to calculate the SHA1 of a file there is a [Microsoft utility](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841290) for that.

Comment: Hi, @martin , it maybe does explain everything for people who understand atleast little bit from what c++ is about, but i have no idea what is library or how to use it(ok should be similar to php classes, but still) .

Comment: what i need is someone to edit the code i gave or to tell me how to edit it so the argument passed as info hash would be encoded by sha1 encoding, because i need it to be in table like sha1(word) because im doing the same with php and after i need to match them two together.

Comment: @Treat: You can't expect us to help if you're unwilling to put *any effort at all* into solving this yourself.

Comment: @greg i do not want to be a c++ coder, i do not need to know that language at all. I just need to know how can i do this (i will show how it can be done in php)

Comment: I do:
sha1("cat")

PHP returns 9d989e8d27dc9e0ec3389fc855f142c3d40f0c50

how can i do that in C++?

Answer (score 0):

If you have (header-only) Boost (v1.68+) available, there's a SHA1 implementation inside uuid:

```cpp
#include <boost/uuid/detail/sha1.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

std::string sha1(const std::string& input) {
    boost::uuids::detail::sha1 sha1;
    sha1.process_bytes(input.data(), input.size());
    unsigned int digest[5];
    sha1.get_digest(digest);
    std::ostringstream hash;
    hash << std::hex << std::setfill('0');
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        // Swap byte order because of Little Endian
        const char* tmp = reinterpret_cast<char*>(digest);
        hash << std::setw(2) << static_cast<int>(static_cast<uint8_t>(tmp[i * 4 + 3]))
             << std::setw(2) << static_cast<int>(static_cast<uint8_t>(tmp[i * 4 + 2]))
             << std::setw(2) << static_cast<int>(static_cast<uint8_t>(tmp[i * 4 + 1]))
             << std::setw(2) << static_cast<int>(static_cast<uint8_t>(tmp[i * 4]));
    }
    return hash.str();
}

int main() {
    std::cout << sha1("cat") << std::endl;
    // output: 9d989e8d27dc9e0ec3389fc855f142c3d40f0c50
}
```