# Is there a simple C or C++ function that calculates the sha1 hash of a string?

Tags: c++, encryption, hash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sha1 function in cpp (C++)Hi,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189257/sha1-function-in-cpp-chi)

I was just looking for a function that calculates the sha1 hash of string and returns the result.

Comment: C (and to a lesser extent, C++) are not known for having lots of built-in functionality. You'll probably be able to find a library that has one or more functions for this purpose. Which language are you using?

Comment: ... and here I am, direct from Googling!

Answer (score 50):

Not built-in. Try openssl's crypto library.

(https://www.openssl.org/source/)

(https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/include/openssl/sha.h)

(https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/SHA1.html)

```
#include <openssl/sha.h>

int main()
{  
  const unsigned char str[] = "Original String";
  unsigned char hash[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH]; // == 20

  SHA1(str, sizeof(str) - 1, hash);

  // do some stuff with the hash

  return 0;
}
```

Link with `-lssl`, which will imply `-lcrypto`. If you are linking statically you might need to link both.

Comment: FYI: need to link with `-lcrypto` to compile.  E.g. `gcc example.c -lcrypto`.

Comment: Also: the package to install on Debian based GNU/Linuxes is `libssl-dev`.

Comment: And the package to install on Fedora 36 is `openssl-devel`.

Answer (score 10):

[CryptoPP](http://www.cryptopp.com/) is a great C++ library for cryptographic functions. It has a method for calculating a SHA1 digest. See examples of the hashing functions [here](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Hash_Functions).

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/csha1.aspx#csha1is

Also, this question was already addressed on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189257/sha1-function-in-cpp-chi) thread. They have a link for some further help. Check it out.

Answer (score 2):

[libgcrypt](http://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gcrypt/Available-hash-algorithms.html#Available-hash-algorithms)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this post on Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-337664.html).  They suggest looking in `libcrypt`.

Also there's an implementation [here](http://home.utah.edu/~nahaj/c/sha/sha.c.html) but I'm not sure what the license is.

Answer (score -4):

You need to use a library.  [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/uuid/index.html) has this functionality.

Comment: Instead of just linking to the Boost home page, could you link to the library that you claim exists, or at least mention that library's name?